# execvp not working with command line argument

Tags: c, shell, fork, system-calls, execvp

I am working on this program to run the shell command given via command line argument using system calls `execvp()` and `fork()`. Here arglist is a 2D array which contains the command name and its argument list. I am passing command name as the first argument and the arglist array as the second argument. But it is not working. man page of `execvp()` says that it will look for the given command by default in the directories defined by PATH variable, that is why I am passing just command name.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void executeCommand(char *command,char **arglist){

    int pid;
    int status;

    pid=fork();

    printf("%s %s\n",command,arglist[1]);

    if(pid == -1){
        printf("fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(pid==0){

        if(execvp(command,arglist) == -1){
            printf("execution of command failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else {

        while(wait(&status) != pid);

        printf("Parent Exiting\n");
        exit(0);
    }


}


int main(int argc,char **argv){

    char **arglist,*com;
    int i,k=1;

    if(argc>2){
        arglist = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(argc));
        for(i=0;i<argc-1;i++){
            arglist[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);

        }   
        com = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(argv[1]));      

        strcpy(com,argv[1]);
        for(i=1;i<=(argc-1);i++,k++){
            strcpy(arglist[k],argv[i]);

        }
        arglist[k] = NULL ;
        for(i=0;i<argc;i++){
            printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
        }

        executeCommand(argv[1],arglist);



    }

    //printf("%d\n",argc);




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So whats the output you are getting? command failed?

Comment: When you say that it is not `working with command line arguments` you mean that `execvp` complete successfully without additional arguments? Also, since you mentioned `PATH`, have you tried given it a command with the full path?

Comment: It seems that you are also copying the command name in the arglist, maybe thats why it is failing

Comment: @Arpit Sometimes it fails, sometimes segmentation-fault, and sometimes simply nothing happens. I think command name is supposed to be copied as the first argument in argument list

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira Yes It works with hard coded arguments.. Simply giving the command name works.. No full path required

Comment: @DharakKharod: when you are initializing the arglist then instead of (argc-1) change it to (argc). Buffer overflow is happening

Comment: @DharakKharod: And also instead of hard-coding the initialization to 1024, it will be better if you use strlen(argv[i]). This will save lot of memory.

Comment: @Arpit Yes It worked! Moreover I was initializing the arglist index k with 1 instead of 0 .. Thanks!

Comment: To make the program clean, make sure to add calls to free the memory you allocated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating enough space for the command when you do

```
com = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(argv[1]));
```

since it doesn't make space for the terminator, you need to add one to the result of strlen as in

```
com = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(1+strlen(argv[1])));
```

Even easier would be to use [strdup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) instead of malloc/strcpy. Then you just need to say

```
com = strdup(argv[1]);
```

and

```
arglist[k] = strdup(argv[i]);
```

and remove all of the mallocs except the one creating the space for arglist itself.

Comment: Also, you are not supposed to cast malloc return address in C.